# Order by featured DESC and Rand() - Laravel

Tags: laravel

Usecase: Show top 3 featured images randomly then followed by non featured images with paginating. I have around 17 featured images.

How I can random with orderBy.

DB:featured: 0 or 1 in DB

```
$images = Images::OrderBy('featured', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: no, my use case is different, I am ordering column first then need top 3 from that then show rest as per pagination limit.

Comment: Maybe you should be filtering on `featured = 1` instead of ordering by it, then... assuming that there are always at least 3 featured images.

Comment: then how i apply limit on that? I need only 3 featured

Answer (score 0):

Try

Without Pagination

```php
//Latest 3 featured images
$top3FeaturedImages = Images::where('featured', 1)
    ->latest()
    ->take(3)
    ->get();

$randomUnfeaturedImages = Images::where('featured', 0)
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->take(7)
    ->get();

$result = $top3FeaturedImages->concat($randomUnfeaturedImages);
```

With Pagination

```
$featuredImages = Images::where('featured', 1)
    ->latest()
    ->take(3)
    ->get();

$randomUnfeaturedImages = Images::where('featured', 0)
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->paginate(7);

//In this case you need to pass 2 variables to the view $featuredImages & paginated $randomUnfeaturedImages
```

Comment: This will give top 10 featured, I need 3 featured and 7 non featured.

Comment: Do you require pagination as well? If pagination is not required then there's a simple solution

Comment: with pagination

Comment: @Zack Have updated answer with two options  - see if it works for you

Comment: in one query, cant have multiple

Comment: I don't think it's possible in a single query - to apply two opposing where conditions and also limit rows for each of the where on the same table. Not sure